# Excel MAX and IF with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, max

Got transaction numbers in column A (no duplicates) and persons (numbers) in column E (duplicates may occur). To find the highest number in A for each person in E, and mark it out as "Last event" or "other" in each row, I've done this in column Z:

```
{=IF(A2=MAX(IF(E2=$E$2:$E$50000,$A$2:$A$50000,"")),"Last event","other")}
```

Formula works, and points out "Last event" in only 1 row (for each person number), and "other" in all other rows holding the same person number.

But now I need to add another column in my search. Column S need to be added as a condition when cell value in S is "JobList" (duplicates may occur). Result should be the same: "Last event" in only 1 row for each person number + JobList, and "other" in all other rows.

I've been struggeling all day about this, but can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is something like `AND(E2=$E$2:$E$50000,S2=$S$2:$S$50000)` as condition sufficient? In EXCEL 365 there is also a `MAXIFS`-function.

Comment: Or as a non-array-formula `IF(A2=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((E2=$E$2:$E$50000)*(S2=$S$2:$S$50000)*($A$2:$A$50000))),"Last event","other")`. untested

Comment: Couldn't get the first one to work, but the second non-array version works perfect. Thanks a lot  [OverflowStacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10068520/overflowstacker) for helping out :)

Comment: Is the `SUMPRODUCT` part really needed ? `=IF(A2=MAX((E2=$E$2:$E$50000)*("Joblist"=$S$2:$S$50000)*($A$2:$A$50000)),"Last event","other")` should be enough. As stated by @OverflowStacker, `=IF(A2=MAXIFS($A$2:$A$50000,$E$2:$E$50000,E2,$S$2:$S$50000,"JobList"),"LastEvent","other")` works too.

Comment: @E.Wiest I'm not sure, if  `MAX` can handle the array-calculations without pressing control shift enter.

Comment: OK, thanks. EDIT : Tested. It works without it (O365 Pro Plus).